# C# UWP RDP Client

Tags: c#, uwp, rdp

How can I implement RDP client in UWP?

I checked the MS samples and I don't see any practical implementation of RDP with UWP.

Is this possible? With WinForms and WPF it as possible but I can't find any sample for UWP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible in pure UWP apps.

However, you could try building the app as a **WPF app**, add modern UI using [XAML Islands](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/11/02/xaml-islands-a-deep-dive-part-1/) and then package the app to publish it as an UWP app on the Microsoft Store using the [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop).

Comment: why Microsoft does not provide an RDP client to UWP? UWP is not new anymore and in other platforms there was a way to integrate an RDP client easily. there any third party software doing this?